# SQlite insert not working

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm writing a C# database winform app and I have a problem executing this query. It throws me this error:

```
SQLite error
near "SELECT": syntax error
```

Can someone help me please? Thanks for any answer or suggestion.

```
"INSERT into subor(idsubor, idpodfk, pnazovfk, datumpravop, podiel, podield, cislozLV,
datumzaradenia, idmajetok)
values (null, " + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + ", 
         '" + comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() + "', 
         '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("d. M. yyyy") + "', 
         '" + textBox2.Text + "',
          " + podield.ToString("0.0000", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ", 
         '" + textBox4.Text + "', 
         '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("d. M. yyyy") + "', 
              SELECT IFNULL(a, '0') AS idmajetok 
              FROM (SELECT MAX(idmajetok) + 1 AS a FROM subor))";
```

Comment: Please show us an actual instance of that concatenated string, too. Only then can we have a clear look at the SQL syntax you're using.

Comment: please put C# code here... and for your self check value of query and write it here.!

Comment: Please, please, please learn about SQL injection attacs! http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/18/please-please-please-learn-about-injection-attacks.aspx

Comment: Thanks for all replies, i was missing parenthesis in my inner select

and i will implement some functions against injections, but is there any danger of injections in inserts statements?

Comment: @OndroTadanai Of course there is. Just imagine that e.g. `textbox4.Text = "xyz', '1.1.1970', '0', 42); DROP TABLE subor;"`. Run your command once and all your data in that table is gone.

Comment: ah, im going to rewrite it immediatelly, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# string/SQLite SQL mixture still seems somewhat confusing, but one possible issue that I'm seeing is as follows:

You are using a `SELECT` statement to indicate one of the values in your `VALUES` list. As you can see [in the syntax diagram](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), that `SELECT` statement has to be enclosed in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect some SQL syntax Problem, and i made some changes to your select statement.

Please try out:

```
string sqlInsert = "INSERT into subor(idsubor, idpodfk, pnazovfk, datumpravop, 
podiel,podield, cislozLV, datumzaradenia, idmajetok) values (null, '" + 
comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + 
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("d.M.yyyy") + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + 
podield.ToString("0.0000", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ",'" + 
textBox4.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("d.M.yyyy") + "','" + "SELECT 
IFNULL(a, '0') AS idmajetok FROM (SELECT MAX(idmajetok) + 1 AS a FROM subor) )');";}
```

Comment: ....
,'" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("d.M.yyyy") + "','" + "SELECT 
IFNULL(a, '0') AS idmajetok FROM (SELECT MAX(idmajetok) + 1 AS a FROM subor) )');";}

i think this will insert select statement into table, wont parse it